# UNNotificationServiceExtension: memory limit?

Tags: ios, ios10

I'm trying to implement UNNotificationServiceExtension, but my code seems to fail often, simply stating the

```
Program ended with exit code: 0"
```

I am trying to use the FMDB Sqlite3 module in the extension and it seems as though I may be running into memory limits inside the extension. Are there any documented limits for memory in these extensions? Are there any strategies to help me take them into account, or am I just going to have to accept that I can't put complex functionality into the extension?

Running it through Instruments shows that it only reaches 3.24MB. And NSExtensionMain is 68% of that, so I don't think I can bring that down by a lot.

Comment: Have you found an answer to that? My extensions is also crashing when trying to download bigger images.

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. I had to really cut down what my extension was doing to not have it hit the memory limit.

Comment: Is this memory limit documented somewhere? In my case I'm simply trying to download an image but this happens when the image is bigger than 5MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit as of 05/18/18 is 12MB. I verified this by allocating too much memory and saw a Console message from the kernel stating the process was terminated by violating the hard limit of 12MB.